# In SQL Server, is it possible to find all databases that contain some schema, without using dynamic SQL?

Tags: sql-server, schema

I know how to find all databases that contain some schema, using dynamic SQL, but can it be done without dynamic SQL?

Comment: what is the problem with dynamic sql?

Comment: If it can be done by querying a system view, that would be more efficient than dynamic SQL.

Comment: show us current query

Answer (score 0):

There is no server-wide DMV containing such information. You have to either construct one monstrous dynamic query touching all databases, or execute a small query in each database. To use the later, you can use [sp_MSforeachdb](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1414/run-same-command-on-all-sql-server-databases-without-cursors/) (or some [alternative](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/)) to query each of the databases, like this (replace `Staging` with the name of the schema you are looking for):

```
DECLARE @command varchar(1000) 
SELECT @command = 'USE ? if schema_id(N''Staging'') is not null select db_name() as DatabaseName' 
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @command
```

When used properly, dynamic SQL is not inefficient. Don't hesitate to use it when appropriate.